# Get the sum of turnover in the last row SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

**Solution:** I had to add a `WHERE` clause to both `SELECT` queries.

---

I'm working on a SQL Server 2008 database.

I'm trying to write a SQL query to return a resultset like that :

```
    date     | turnover_centrale    | turnover_public       
+------------+----------------------+--------------------
| 2017-02-14 | 233.34               | 383.83                    
| 2017-03-14 | 142.81               | 166.8                  
| 2017-04-14 | 173.25               | 250.51                
| 2017-05-14 | 186.96               | 245.08                
| 2017-06-14 | 61.26                | 97.67                 
| 2017-07-14 | 262.98               | 356.16                
| 2017-08-14 | 89.88                | 162.38               
| 2017-09-14 | 250.32               | 381.47                
| 2017-10-14 | 386.06               | 581.96                
| Total      | Result of the column | Result of the column
```

My SQL query is :

```
SELECT 
    CLC_DATE, CLC_PRIX_CENTRALE, CLC_PRIX_PUBLIC 
FROM 
    ##.dbo.CLIENTS_CONSO
WHERE 
    CF_USER = :ref

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    NULL, SUM(CLC_PRIX_CENTRALE), SUM(CLC_PRIX_PUBLIC) 
FROM 
    ##.dbo.CLIENTS_CONSO
```

The result of the last row is unfortunately false :(

So do you have a better solution ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is false because the total query is missing the WHERE clause?

Comment: If i put the WHERE clause in the total query, i have a result with 500 row.
https://imgur.com/37MWWe5

Comment: You should have WHERE clause to both the SELECT queries

Answer (score 0):

Considering that each date only has one entry, perhaps:

```
WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(date,[date]) AS [date], turnover_centrale, turnover_public
    FROM (VALUES 
                ('20170214',233.34,383.83),                    
                ('20170314',142.81,166.8 ),                 
                ('20170414',173.25,250.51),                
                ('20170514',186.96,245.08),                
                ('20170614',61.26 ,97.67 ),                
                ('20170714',262.98,356.16),                
                ('20170814',89.88 ,162.38),               
                ('20170914',250.32,381.47),                
                ('20171014',386.06,581.96)) V([date],turnover_centrale, turnover_public))
SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),[date],120),'Total') AS [date],
       SUM(turnover_centrale) AS turnover_centrale,
       SUM(turnover_public) AS turnover_public
FROM VTE
GROUP BY [date] WITH ROLLUP;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot ! 
My table is build like that :

```
    https://i.imgur.com/csXl8vl.png
    <br>
    CLC_DATE = the date of consumption, it's corresponding to each month in a year.
    <br>
    CLC_PRIX_PUBLIC = the turnover public
    <br>
    CLC_PRIX_CENTRALE = the turnover centrale
```

The WHERE clause is important, beacause its the gateway from the client and his consumnption

With your solution, it doesn't work.